# manipulate multiple parts of a string in python, removing one part replacing another

Tags: python, python-3.x

suppose i have a string like this `"/article/blah-blah-blah"`

how do i get the substring `"blah blah blah"` in this exact format (to clarify dashes `-` are replaced by spaces and the `/articles/` part completely removed)

is there a way to use multiple arguments in str.replace maybe or any other way?

Comment: `os.path.basename(uri).replace("-"," ")` ? your question is too broad.

Comment: `uri.split('/')[-1].replace('-', ' ')` or without external libraries

Comment: its not broad string manipulation is the thing in question here, i already have the URI as a string in  a variable so i am asking about two things namely:
1. remove the text between the two forward slashes along with the slashes themselves. 
2. replace the "-" characters with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
 re.sub('/[^>]+/', '', "stringGoesHere".replace('-', " "))
```

**This above line gave me exactly what i am looking for.**

Input: `/article/bears-love-berries`

Output: `'bears love berries'`